# Take all element distinct without repetition xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

From My XML code I want to take all of the items at once without repetition.
My Xml code is:

```
      <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
         <IMMUTABLE_ID>9814</IMMUTABLE_ID>
         <LIGHT_DESCRIPTION_LIST>             
            <LIGHT_DESCRIPTION>                  
              <LIGHT_SUPPORT_HEIGHT>198</LIGHT_SUPPORT_HEIGHT>
            </LIGHT_DESCRIPTION>
            <LIGHT_DESCRIPTION>                  
              <LIGHT_SUPPORT_HEIGHT>166</LIGHT_SUPPORT_HEIGHT>
            </LIGHT_DESCRIPTION>
            <LIGHT_DESCRIPTION>                  
              <LIGHT_SUPPORT_HEIGHT>122</LIGHT_SUPPORT_HEIGHT>
            </LIGHT_DESCRIPTION>
            <LIGHT_DESCRIPTION>                  
              <LIGHT_SUPPORT_HEIGHT>76</LIGHT_SUPPORT_HEIGHT>
            </LIGHT_DESCRIPTION>
            <LIGHT_DESCRIPTION>                  
              <LIGHT_SUPPORT_HEIGHT>31</LIGHT_SUPPORT_HEIGHT>
            </LIGHT_DESCRIPTION>
            <LIGHT_DESCRIPTION>                  
              <LIGHT_SUPPORT_HEIGHT>31</LIGHT_SUPPORT_HEIGHT>
            </LIGHT_DESCRIPTION>              
         </LIGHT_DESCRIPTION_LIST>
      <NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT>
```

I want the sequence: 198 166 122 76 31.

I wrote this code xslt 1.0, but I can not get a correct result:

```
<xsl:for-each select="LIGHT_DESCRIPTION">
    <xsl:for-each select="LIGHT_SUPPORT_HEIGHT">
        <xsl:if test=".=not(preceding::LIGHT_SUPPORT_HEIGHT[1][preceding::IMMUTABLE_ID=$EF])">
            <span style="font-size:9pt; text-align:center; ">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </span>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

EF is a variable of current node (IMMUTABLE ID) and I use this to remain inside this node.

Can "you" give me more instructions? THANKS

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't match the example XML - where does `IMMUTABLE_ID` come from?

Comment: immutable_ID is a variable that identify every node... there is a lot of this node light description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard approach to grouping problems like this in XSLT 1.0 is called "Muenchian grouping" - essentially you define a *key* that groups nodes that should be treated as "the same", and then use a trick with `generate-id` to process just the first node in each group.

In this case the grouping constraint is a combination of the `LIGHT_SUPPORT_HEIGHT` value itself, and the value of the containing `NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT`'s `IMMUTABLE_ID`:

```
<xsl:key name="supportHeightKey" match="LIGHT_SUPPORT_HEIGHT"
    use="concat(., '|', ancestor::NTC_LIGHTLISTPRODUCT[1]/IMMUTABLE_ID)" />
```

Now you can pick out the unique values using

```
<!-- assuming the current context is LIGHT_DESCRIPTION_LIST -->
<xsl:for-each select="LIGHT_DESCRIPTION/LIGHT_SUPPORT_HEIGHT[
     generate-id() = generate-id(
        key('supportHeightKey', concat(., '|', current()/../IMMUTABLE_ID))[1])]">
  <span style="font-size:9pt; text-align:center; ">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </span>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: thanks for your explanation was very helpful for understand e solve my XSLT problem.