# split letter from number in a sorted list xslt 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

This is XML code you can see this items group sorted by letter and number:

```
<LIGHT_RANGE_LIST>
  <RANGE>W19</RANGE>
  <RANGE>W17</RANGE>
  <RANGE>R15</RANGE>
  <RANGE>R13</RANGE>
  <RANGE>R11</RANGE>
</LIGHT_RANGE_LIST>
```

This is my XSLT code:

```
<xsl:for-each select="RANGE">
    <span style="text-align:center;font-family:Univers Condensed; font-size:9pt; ">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </span>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I have provisionally applied this template, obtaining this result:

```
W19
W17
R15
R13
R11
```

My ultimate goal is to have the following output:

```
W19
R15
```

For each letter, take the letter with the largest numeric value - given that it is possible to have a single letter (not two)

Comment: Please add more of your (if not the entire) XSLT stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="by_letter" match="RANGE" use="substring(., 1, 1)" />

<xsl:template match="/">
<div>
    <!-- for each distinct letter -->
    <xsl:for-each select="LIGHT_RANGE_LIST/RANGE[generate-id() = generate-id(key('by_letter', substring(., 1, 1))[1])]">
        <!-- process the subgroup -->
        <xsl:for-each select="key('by_letter', substring(., 1, 1))">
            <xsl:sort select="substring(., 2)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
            <xsl:if test="position()=1">
                <span><xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</div>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262560/merging-set-of-elements-based-on-a-common-attribute-in-xslt-1-0/20264823#20264823).

Comment: @francesco this is another example of the Muenchian grouping method I described in [my answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20547954/592139) - most grouping problems in XSLT 1.0 can be solved by some variation of this technique so it's well worth spending some time to understand it.

Comment: Ian this XSLT is very difficult...I dont study this, I am a VB programmer...and create this XSLT project without studing and only with Your and My contribution is is a Goal. Thanks for your precious help :-)

Comment: @francesco 1. It's not *that* difficult; even I got it eventually. 2. Using code you don't understand is like taking a medicine prescribed for someone else; it may seem helpful at first, but it can do some serious damage down the road.

Comment: :-) I like your comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

At the end I study your version and I apply this, that is similar but created by me. Thank you for your cooperation.

Variable name: 
Lcorrente->current letter 
LSuccessiva->next letter
Ncorrente->current number
Nsuccessiva->Next number

```
<xsl:for-each select="RANGE">

<!-- Prendo le lettere-->
<xsl:variable name="LCorrente" select="substring(.,1,1)"/>                                                                                                                          
<xsl:variable name="LSuccessiva" select="substring(preceding-sibling::RANGE[1]  [preceding::IMMUTABLE_ID=$EF],1,1)"/>

<!-- Prendo i numeri-->
<xsl:variable name="NCorrente" select="number(substring(.,2,string-length(.)-1))"/>
<xsl:variable name="NSuccessiva" select="number(substring(following-sibling::RANGE[1][preceding::IMMUTABLE_ID=$EF],2,string-length(following-sibling::RANGE[1][preceding::IMMUTABLE_ID=$EF])-1))"/>

<xsl:when test="$LCorrente!=$LSuccessiva">
    <span style="font-family:Univers Condensed; font-size:9pt; color:orange; text-align:center;">
        <xsl:value-of select="$LCorrente"/>                                                                         
    </span>     

    <span style="font-family:Univers Condensed; font-size:9pt; color:red; text-align:center; ">
        <xsl:value-of select="$NCorrente"/>
    </span>
</xsl:when>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: This approach is fine if you know that items within each "group" (adjacent items with the same first letter) are guaranteed to be in descending numerical order - if you need to apply sorting to each group to extract the maximum number then you'll have to use a Muenchian-style approach.  Within a `for-each` that has an `xsl:sort` specification, the sibling axes still refer to the original document order, not the sorted order.

Comment: Thanks IAn :-)xslt starts to like me :-)